# path issue with include in PHP

Tags: php, path, include

I have an index.php in root and a 'includes' folder containing header.php and footer.php.I included header and footer in index.php and it works fine but in header and footer I include some different files in config folder in root.

I know that I should use "../config/config.php" but it works with 'config/config.php'.

I included header and footer in index.php and I should use path according to the index that I included to ???

what if I include one file in several folders ???

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `__DIR__` it will give you the path compared to where your current file exist, also try to use `include_once` instead of `include`

> **DIR** : The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
> dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
> unless it is the root directory.

Include your file like this from within your header.php and footer.php:

include_once **DIR**.'/../config/config.php';

do the same technique for other files

Answer (score 1):

Yes your path should be according to index.php that's mean your root directory, not your includes folder.
At any time you can check such issues by

```
echo __DIR__;
```

to make sure from your path.